# How to use CAGradientLayer in layoutSubview by changing orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, gradient, layoutsubviews

I have created a `CAGradientLayer` in a `layoutSubview`. This works, but if I change orientation it seems that the old frame doesn't disappear.

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{ 
    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [GradientClass getGradient];
    bgLayer.frame = [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0] frame];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because `layoutSubviews` is called again when you rotate the device, causing a second `CAGradientLayer` to be created.

All you should need to do is just keep a reference to your `CAGradientLayer` and just modify its frame.

```
// Define bgLayer in your interface
@property (strong, nonatomic) CAGradientLayer *bgLayer;

- (void) layoutSubviews
{ 
    if (!self.bgLayer) {
        self.bgLayer = [GradientClass getGradient];
        [self.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
    }

    self.bgLayer.frame = [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0] frame];
}
```